# how to block a command from terminal?

Tags: sudo, root

I don't want any users in my machine to use a command in my machine other than root user. The command is given below.

"sudo -E su"

For security reasons

Comment: What do you **really** want to do? What do you want to accomplish from restricting that command? `sudo su` switches a user to root, but blocking this command won't stop them from running commands as root, nor will it stop them from logging in as root too, because as bodhi.zazen pointed out, they will still be able to run `sudo -i` which also takes them into a root shell.

Comment: "For security reasons" would changing the admin password and removing anyone from admin permissions not be better, security wise? (by the way: that is the default Ubuntu installs with ;) )

Answer (score 1):

You are asking no other user can do sudo to be a root user.

you just need to edit a line in sudoers file.

> vim /etc/sudoers

change the line from

> %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

to

> **your-username** ALL:(ALL) ALL

after editing no other user except you can use sudo command.
This is kicking all other users from sudoers file. except you.

Comment: It would be better suggest to use `visudo` instead of `vim`, [visudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/visudo.8.html) provides basic sanity checks, and checks for parse errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each user a separate account (or create at least one non-admin user). Users in the admin group will be able to access root, via `sudo -i` or any other method.

Comment: No, if we edit sudoers file then not even a chance.

Answer (score 0):

> Lshell is configured via an INI file. By default, it holds a whitelist of allowed commands, but it can be easily configured to prohibit user from using a specific command.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90998/block-particular-command-in-linux-for-specific-user